# Is there a way to check if a Generic type is a subtype of another type in C#?

Tags: c#

Given a generic type `T` I would want to check if it is a subtype of another type `Other`.
I would expect that `T is Other` would work, but the only way I got it to work was with `typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Other))`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Bellow there is an example usage:

```
public class Animal { }

public class AnimalFactory
{
    class FakeAnimal : Animal { }

    static FakeAnimal fakeCached = new FakeAnimal();

    public static Animal CreateAnimal<T>() where T : Animal, new()
    {
        //if (T is FakeAnimal) // -> Doesn't compile
        if (typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(FakeAnimal))) // -> Works fine
        {
            return fakeCached ;
        }
        return new T();
    }
}
```

*Note: The example above is simplified, the concrete use case is more complex. I'm not concerned with anything else in the example other than the line that doesn't compile.*

Comment: Perhaps add an override for `CreateAnimal<>` like `public static Animal CreateAnimal<T>() where T : FakeAnimal, new()` and let the restriction do the work for you?  Though I'm not sure if overrides for this are supported.

Comment: BTW: in C# we speak of "generic methods/types", not of "templates". For people also knowing C++, the difference is quite relevant.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your motivation. What do you want to achieve that you currently can't? Why are you asking this question? What's wrong with the current way you are doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `typeof(T) == typeof(FakeAnimal)`? Otherwise you would return an object of the wrong type if you request a subtype of `FakeAnimal`. Or make `FakeAnimal` a `sealed` class to prevent this situation.

Comment: @KlausGütter I've edited the question to use "generic" instead of "template"

Answer (score 1):

The pattern matching statement `x is FakeAnimal` requires x be an object.  `T` is a type name, which is why you must get the `Type` object via `typeof(T)` and use that object's `IsAssignableTo` method.